# RLS and Viewer and Member Permissions in New Workspace

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

We have a workspace that was recently updated. Inside this workspace, we have a Power BI dataset with RLS. The primary use cases for this dataset is two-fold:

1. Users consume the pre-built report with their filter context applied.
2. Users utilize "Analyze in Excel" to build additional Pivot Table reports based on the data set.

This is what we have noticed...

1. When the users are set as a Member of the workspace, the RLS is pretty much ignored completely, and they see the data with all records.
2. When the users are set to Viewer, the RLS works properly, but then they are not able to use "Analyze in Excel".

I understand the permissions requirement around not allowing "Viewers" access to "Analyze in Excel". That is by design. However, what are we missing about the new workspaces that have caused us not to be able to achieve both of these results? We have confirmed that the RLS is in place correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that viewers cannot use analyze in Excel function? Do you have a reference for that (docs)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, since all members are contributors in the workspace, they can all access all data, regardless of RLS. You can disallow edits for members, in that case, RLS will be working for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#using-rls-with-workspaces-in-power-bi

Also, I can analyze datasets in Excel even though I am not a member of certain workspaces, but datasets were shared with me.